# How to reference variable names in a list?

Tags: r

I am able to reference a value of a list with `[[ ]]`, but how do I reference the variable name of that value.

In this example,
`a <- list("apple" = 1, "orange" = 2)`
I can reference the value of apple and orange by using `a[[1]]` and `a[[2]]` respectively. But I'm trying to get the name "apple". I tried using `a[1]` but it returns everything. I'd like to return `apple` as a character like this "apple" for passing it inside a for loop later.

Comment: `a %>% names %>% .[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in `names` of `a`.

```
names(a)
#[1] "apple"  "orange"
```

To get the first value use `names(a)[1]`

```
names(a)[1]
#[1] "apple"
```

Also similar is `names(a[1])`.